# Php/Magento comparison operator always returning true?

Tags: php, string, magento, comparison

I am trying to use a simple if comparison and it seems to always render as true.

```
if ($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image') == $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()) ){
    echo 'true';
}
```

I know for a fact that these two items are not equal (if you don't know Magento, they are used to get urls for product images in different ways).

I use these methods in

```
<img src="<?php $this->helper...etc ?>" />
```

And if I echo them, they are clearly different.  Is the comparison somehow comparing whether they exist or not and they are both returning true?  If so, how can I make it so it compares them as strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var_dump($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image'));
var_dump($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile());
```

My guess is each of the above `var_dump` statements will dump a PHP object to the browser/output-environment, (or cause possibly cause a "memory exhaustion" fatal error if you don't have xDebug installed).

Now try this

```
var_dump((string) $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image'));
var_dump((string) $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile());
```

You should see your identical strings.  The `init` method returns an object, which means when you're doing your equality check, you're checking for quality on **the helper objects**.  In Magento, objects instantiated as helpers are, effectively, singletons, which means multiple instantiations will return **the same** object, which is what object equality checks for.

When you cast these objects as strings, (with `(string)`), PHP converts the object to a string (using the `__toString` method defined on the object.

When you use an object in "string context" (in an echo or print statement, or somewhere else PHP expects a string), PHP will automatically cast the object as a string.

So if you want to do an equality check, cast the objects as strings first.

```
if ((string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image') == (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()) ){
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Great Stuff! Appreciate it!  (Ps your Magento tutorials/website is awesome)

Comment: Quick additional question.  I am trying to save resources by saving the call: `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())` As a variable, and then in the if statements using if((string)$variable == ....)  And it doesn't work the same.  Why is this?

Comment: Not enough information the follow what you're asking there.  You might want to try posting a second question with further details of what happens.